# How to skip invalid fields on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is it possible to skip invalid values when I'm saving an entity with SaveChanges and save only valid fields?

It's pretty simple to skip on entities level, but I'm not able to find a way of doing that on fields level.

Comment: You can validate all the fields before calling savechanges() and assign the value to the entity only if it pass validation

Comment: Care should be taken that u pass values satisfying all the necessary constraints placed on your entity

Comment: Why do you need that? You will end up with half-old and half-new objects, and users which don't understand where half of information gone

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy: it's a business requirement

Comment: @Abdul Hameed: that would be awesome, but how can I do that? manually?

Comment: @AlexK how can this be done on an entity level? I'm trying to skip all invalid entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muhammad's answer gave me great idea. The solution is pretty simple:

```
        try
        {
            context.Entry(objInDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exception = ex as DbEntityValidationException;
            if (exception != null)
            {
                exception.EntityValidationErrors.ToList().ForEach(error =>
                {
                    error.ValidationErrors.ToList().ForEach(validationError =>
                    {
                        error.Entry.Property(validationError.PropertyName).IsModified = false;
                    });
                });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```